# deployed react app does not return content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, react-router

I have been doing the tinder clone app and there was no error when I am running the development server and after I deployed it to **firebase**. The app has no content.

I have tried to debug and opened chrome console and it said
*** Unexpected token '<' ***

and I thought some glitch might have happened with firebase. So, I tried to host it in **Github pages**. and I did but still the page does not load any content.

but when I opened the console. it does not show the above error. it said *** Minified React error #152; ***

I have no idea what happened. my development server is running fine locally without any error.

here is my GitHub link : https://github.com/rooben-me/tinder-clone

live sites :

Firebase hosted site : https://tinder-clone-1bf69.web.app/,
Github pages : https://rooben-me.github.io/tinder-clone/

Much appreciated

Comment: Hi @ruban-kumar, welcome to SO.
Have you googled `Minified React error #152`?  Someone else may have run into this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

This issue is a bit obscure, but the issue boils down to having comments in your return statements:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    // some comment
    ...
  )
}
```

In your repo, the issue seems to be here:

https://github.com/rooben-me/tinder-clone/blob/master/src/Header.js#L13

### Solution

Delete the comment from the return statement:

```
function Header({ backButton }) {
  const histroy = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className="header">
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Extra

Here is the relative Github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8687

What makes this error so hard to debug is that development builds work fine, it's only until you build for production, does this obscure error pop up with very little hint as to what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. I have just started to learn to react js. I have fixed the bug.

Comment: @rubankumar no problem! This was one I dealt with a few months ago, so glad we got a stackoverflow answer up that could potentially help future devs